# How to add the second DetailBand block to the hierarchy?

Tags: devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui, devexpress-wpf

Currently, I am working on creation of subreport  and
want to add a second DetailBand to my hierarchy. For now, It looks:

[image: Current state of hierarchy]

I want to get like this:

[image]

With additional DetailBand, I couldn't implement it for a few hours. Unfortunately, I can use only code for the creative structure of the subreport and after I added one more detail it didn't appear at all.

I can't share the code, so I hope it was clear enough, but please ask if you need any clarification. Thank you!